# Change the key mapping of Github Copilot autocomplete in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2022, github-copilot

Is there any way to change the mapping for Copilot autocomplete in Visual Studio 2022?  I don't see it in the standard Copilot mapping options. Intellicode autocomplete and CoPilot are at odds and I'd rather not lose either if I can help it.

I checked the standard keyboard mapping in Visual studio.  It appears as thought there's a keymapping for autocomplete in general and I'm unable to separate the two.  If that's the case, I'll just turn Copilot off but I was hoping someone might know if there's a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to activate built in autocomplete and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept. Then, use <kbd>Tab</kbd> for co-pilot auto complete. To use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter an actual tab character, you have to reject the co-pilot suggestion first. I can't find a way to change the key bindings to be better in VS-2022 but, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> allows you to access the functionality you are requesting without changing key bindings.